# What data structure to use with arbitrarily large integer numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, largenumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What data-structure should I use to create my own “BigInteger” class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224092/what-data-structure-should-i-use-to-create-my-own-biginteger-class)

Out of pure interest, I am trying to design a type that can hold an *arbitrarily large* integer. I want to support four basic operations `[+, -, *, /]` and optimise for speed of those operations.

I was thinking about some sort of a doubly-linked list and a bit flag to indicate positive or negative value. But I am not really sure how to add, for example, to large numbers of different sizes. Shall I walk to the last element of both numbers and then return back (using the *second* reverse pointer to the previous element).

```
 123456789     //one large number
+      123     //another large number with different size
```

**Providing I can have an arbitrarily large memory, what is the best data structure for this task?**

I would appreciate a small hint and any comments on worst-case complexity of the arithmetic operations. Thanks!

Comment: You mean like a BigInteger or BigDecimal in Java?

Comment: if you're working in c (or c++, or just curious) then the book c interfaces and implementations develops a library like this - http://www.amazon.com/Interfaces-Implementations-Techniques-Creating-Reusable/dp/0201498413

Comment: http://www.google.de/search?q=java+bigint . First link says: "Immutable arbitrary-precision integers".

Comment: What I can't understand is why someone would use a linked-list for this

Comment: To clarify - do you mean **arbitrarily large** numbers (numbers with no upper bound), or **infinitely large** numbers (as in set theory)?

Comment: @oleksii, no, it's not. If you think about it it is not a good reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually one would go for an array/vector in this case, perhaps little-endian (lowest-significant word first). If you implement in-place operations, use a constant factor when growing the array, then amortized complexity for the reallocation remains O(1).

All operations should be doable in O(n) run time where n is the size of the input. **EDIT**: No, of course, multiplication and division will need more, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794853/946850) says it's at least O(N log N).

Just out of curiosity: Why are you reimplementing the wheel? Find [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java) an implementation in Java. C# has one with .NET 4.0, too. While it might be a good exercise to implement this yourself (I remember myself doing it once), if you just need the functionality then it's there in many computing environments already.

Comment: @oleksii Inside is basically an array of "digits" (and some bookkeeping info).